# heroku postgres dump - not working locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have done this:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture 
heroku pgbackups:url 
downloaded file from url obtained from above result

Created psql db "abc"
```

Ran this comamnd locally:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean -no-acl --no-owner -U uname -d abc  ~/Downloads/b001.dump
```

output:

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: implied data-only restore
```

I have loaded in 2ways. First created db, and directly ran pg_restore command. Then no tables created.

Then, thinking that dump contains only data, I have run migrations(means create table structure) on the new created db and ran pg_restore command. But still table data is empty.

Comment: You can look at the dump file, it is a normal text file. There should be a lot of `CREATE TABLE` at the top of the file.

Comment: I think I found the problem: you are using `-no-acl` instead of `--no-acl`.. and getting `-a` that means "import only data".

Comment: wowwww, thanks @some, please answer so I can mark as answer

Comment: Added it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted AND vote on it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running the command exactly as you have written you have an error:

You have written `-no-acl` instead of `--no-acl` and are getting `-a` that means:

> -a, --data-only
>
> ```
> Restore only the data, not the schema (data definitions).
> ```

Comment: lol, thanks. Just did this myself. I don't think I would have ever seen that.